# use the file contents line by line and execute

Tags: shell-script, ksh

file.txt

```
servername1:DBNAME1:/u01/app
servername2:DBNAME2:/u01/dbs
servername3:DBNAME3:/u01/app1
```

I want to use above file contents line by line and execute it in shell script

```
command1 hostname=servername1 db=dbanme1 location=/u01/app 
command2 hostname=servername1 db=dbanme1 location=/u01/app
```

after the above commands it has to take the second line values and execute

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: What did you try and how did that fail? There are answers here already for everything you want to do.

Comment: your database names in the list at the top do not match the database names in the shell script .... they do not match in more ways than one

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=':' read -r hostname db location
do
    set -- hostname="$hostname" db="$db" location="$location"
    command1 "$@"
    command2 "$@"
done <file.txt
```

Or, if you need to preserve the positional parameters,

```
while IFS=':' read -r hostname db location
do
    command1 hostname="$hostname" db="$db" location="$location"
    command2 hostname="$hostname" db="$db" location="$location"
done <file.txt
```

Both of these would read `file.txt` line by line, and for each line read the three `:`-delimited fields into the three variables `hostname`, `db` and `location`.  If there are more `:`-delimited fields on any row, these would be added onto the value of `location`.

Then the commands are executed.

Answer (score 1):

Using [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
$ parallel --colsep ":" 'command1 hostname={1} db={2} location={3}; command2 hostname={1} db={2} location={3}' :::: file.txt
```

For each line in `file.txt` the commands are excecuted. The lines get splitted by `:`, so that `{1}`,`{2}`,`{3}` get replaced by the values in the columns.

Note that `parallel` start the processes in parallel. By default the number of jobs running in parallel is the number of cores. You can specify how many jobs are allowed to run in parallel with `-j`. If you need to keep the output in the order of the lines executed, use the `-k` parameter.